# Query to select rows for same Config name but different User IDs

Tags: sql

I have to show on the view a table like this:

[image]

I have a query like this to find Config Names for a single Rep (example: for rep1 in the table image pasted above):

```
SELECT scl.CONFIG_NAME, scl.DEFAULT_VALUE 
    FROM STORE_CONFIGURABLE_LIST scl, CHANNEL_CONFIGURABLES cc, SUBCHANNEL_CONFIGURABLES scc, STORE_CONFIGURABLES sc 
where 
    scl.CONFIG_NAME = cc.CONFIG_NAME (+) 
    and scl.CONFIG_NAME = scc.CONFIG_NAME (+) 
    and scl.CONFIG_NAME = sc.CONFIG_NAME (+) 
    and sc.REP_ID(+) in 'LD29'
    and scc.SUBCHANNEL_ID(+) = 'EXCL' 
    and cc.CHANNEL_ID(+) = 'LD';
```

Now the above query is for - sc.REP_ID(+) in 'LD29' - which will be my 'rep1'. How can I change the SQL Query above for REP_ID = 'D111' (rep2) and show in the tabular format as pasted above?

Thanks!

Comment: Ug... this syntax hurts my head.  *Please* use the standard explicit `Join` syntax.  This implicit `Outer Join` syntax has been deprecated for **[over 25 years!](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt)**.  Most current DBMS's don't even support this syntax anymore...

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If you just replace `LD29` with `D111` in your where clause, will you get the result you want?

Comment: @Siyual Makes me wonder where this question actually came from ^ ^.

Comment: @Robbie A Db newbie here so please be gentle. I do not want to run the query twice, one for LD29 and one for D111. Is there a way I can join or select in or something to get me result in the tabular format i pasted?

Comment: @Siyual, Tim, you guys are right. This is at least 15-20 years of old SQL code which I cannot change because it is running in production, but what I can change is write a new query to achieve the same results. Please help if you could?

Comment: You just need all the results for both? `sc.REP_ID(+) IN ('LD29', 'D111')`

Comment: If you want the tabular output above, I think we'll need more information. Is the Y/N coming from scl.DEFAULT_VALUE? Or is it just supposed to indicate that the config name exists for that rep? Because those are very different queries.

Comment: Y/N will be coming from scl.DEFAULT_VALUE. There will be no NULL values.